# Exec Format error of a 64-bit executable on a 64-bit machine

Tags: unix, gcc, compiler-errors, x86-64

I'm currently working on an implementation of MD5 just because I'm curious and want to get a better understanding of how hashing works. I have 1 file with all the code in it, called `easy_md5.c` and I'm compiling it with the following Makefile:

```
easy_md5: easy_md5.c
    gcc -c easy_md5.c -o easy_md5

clean:
    -rm -f easy_md5.o
    -rm -f easy_md5
```

I ran `chmod +x easy_md5` on the executable to give it permission, and yet I'm getting the following error when I try to run it:

```
[gabe@void easy_md5]$ ./easy_md5 hello
bash: ./easy_md5: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Running `file easy_md5` shows the following:

```
easy_md5: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

and running `arch` confirms my machine has x86-64 architecture. Since its a 64-bit executable, there's no reason it should throw a format error when I try to run it on my 64-bit machine. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create an executable at all.  The `-c` option tells gcc to compile only, and output a relocatable object file.  You'd normally name that file `easy_md5.o` and use it when linking, but the `-o` option forced it to be named `easy_md5` which looks like an executable name even though it isn't.

To compile and link in one step, just drop the `-c`: `gcc easy_md5.c -o easy_md5`.

There were a couple other hints:

> I ran `chmod +x easy_md5` on the executable

When you actually create an executable, this isn't necessary.  gcc sets execute permissions on it for you.

> Running file easy_md5 shows the following:
>
> `easy_md5: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

This indicates an object file.  An actual executable is reported as something like

```
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7108d6b0e7767b20e8db974561938d3bfcbbe12a, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Comment: Note that more modern versions of `file` will report a PIE as `/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, ...`, since it's a special kind of shared object, one that has an entry point in its metadata.  Not just an ordinary `.so`.  And an *actual* elf-type EXEC traditional position-dependent executable is reported as just "executable".